# How can I make my finder refresh a NAS volume mounted using AFP?

Tags: network, finder, nas, afp, refresh

Regrettably I'm using a WD EX2 on my bridged home network (current and 4th gen Airport Extremes), and the finder doesn't refresh my AFP volumes. The NAS is attached on the 4th gen APE.

Anyone have a solution? I've been relaunching the finder and/or connecting/disconnecting. I'm using 10.10.5 on a late 2012 mac mini. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to throw this out here as a workaround if you can't find a better solution.  Many years ago I had a similar situation and this was an issue with the version of **Mac OS X** at the time and **Network Drives** and the lack of a **Refresh** command in **Finder**, which it still doesn't have.  My workaround solution then was an **AppleScript** that I saved as an application and put it in the **Finder Toolbar**.  You could even use it in an **Automator Service** in **Finder** and also assign a *keyboard shortcut* to it if you want.

What this **AppleScript** does is creates a hidden file named ".refresh.tmp" and then deletes it, causing the **Finder** window to refresh/update.

**My Refresh Finder AppleScript Code:**

```
tell application "Finder"
    try
        delete (make new file at (front window) with properties {name:".refresh.tmp"})
    end try
end tell
```

I'm also including some **AppleScript** code I found on **StackOverflow** and has been posted on **AskDifferent** as well although I believe it originated on **StackOverflow**. Not that any of that really matters other then to give credit to someone other then me for it as I didn't write the code below.  It causes all **Finder** windows to refresh by toggling the **View** state between **Icons** and **List** views.

I use both, because when I have lots of **Finder** windows open I prefer to use my original solution on the **Finder Toolbar**, creating/deleting the hidden file, as it's much quicker and usually at that point my focus is on a single **Finder** window.  I have the **Automator Service** set to use a *keyboard shortcut* and the *script* I found on **StackOverflow**. Obviously you're free to choose how to use or not any of what's provided here.

**Refresh Finder AppleScript Code** found at: [Automator Command to Refresh ALL Finder/all Finder Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788558/automator-command-to-refresh-all-finder-all-finder-windows/21790997#21790997)

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theWindows to every Finder window
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in theWindows
        set this_item to item i of theWindows
        set theView to current view of this_item
        if theView is list view then
            set current view of this_item to icon view
        else
            set current view of this_item to list view

        end if
        set current view of this_item to theView
    end repeat
end tell
```

Either one of these **AppleScripts** can be saved as an **AppleScript Application** and or an **Automator Service**, the latter of which a *keyboard shortcut* can be assigned.

Also, as I do not like the generic icon assigned to either, I added a custom *.icns* file from the Internet, in this case a refresh symbol. (A *.png* file can be used as well.)

### **Creating the Refresh Finder AppleScript Application**

1. Open **Script Editor** (or **AppleScript Editor** if applicable).
2. Copy and paste either of the *scripts*, from above, into the **Untitled** document window and then press **Compile**.
3. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to save and set the **File Format:** to **Application** saving it in the **Applications** folder as **Refresh Finder**.
4. Give the **Refresh Finder** application bundle a custom icon.  I used an icon of a refresh symbol found at [IconArchive](http://www.iconarchive.com/search?q=refresh) and used [this one in particular](http://www.iconarchive.com/show/outline-icons-by-iconsmind/Refresh-icon.html) clicking the 'Download ICNS' button.  I opened the downloaded "Iconsmind-Outline-Refresh.icns" file in **Preview** and copied it, pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and then pasted it into the **Get Info** sheet of the **Refresh Finder.app** by first selecting the little icon in the upper left corner of the **Refresh Finder Info** sheet then pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>. (In **Applications** select the **Refresh Finder.app** and press: <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>)
5. Now *drag and drop* the **Refresh Finder** application bundle from the **Applications** folder onto the **Finder Toolbar** where you would like it to be.

It's now ready to be used, click the **Refresh Finder** icon in the **Toolbar** and the Finder window(s*) (*depending on which code your selected) will refresh.

### **Creating the Refresh Finder Automator Service**

1. Open **Automator** selecting **Service**.
2. Set **Service receives selected** to **no input** changing **in any application** to **in Finder**.
   Add a **Run AppleScript** and then copy and paste the **Refresh Finder AppleScript Code** above into the **Run AppleScript** window overwriting the default code.
3. Save the **Service** pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> naming it as **Refresh Finder**.
4. Open **System Preferences** and navigate to **Keyboard  > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services** and scroll to the bottom when under **General** you'll see **Refresh Finder** and select it.  Now click on **add shortcut** and press <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> or: ^⌘R

It's now ready to be use as a **Service**, when **Finder** has focus, using the *keyboard shortcut*: ^⌘R

- Note: You can also give the **Refresh Finder Automator Service** a custom icon as well.  The **Service** is located in `~/Library/Services` and apply the icon in the same manner described above in step 4 of **Creating the Refresh Finder AppleScript Application**.

Comment: I was not able to drag and drop "Refresh Finder.app" onto the toolbar. Then I found another article that says "Hold down the Option + Command keys, and drag the selected item to the Finder toolbar. Release it when you see the plus sign in the green circle." This worked for me.

Comment: @Kamil Slowikowski, This answer was written over 6 years ago and was accurate as written at that time. That said, **Apple** continually makes changes to the **OS** and additional steps are required as you found out.